# flutter win 10 after upgrade 1.22 to 2.2.0 full error path packages

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Windows 10 vs code `1.56.2`

```
I'm using flutter 1.22.
I'm trying to upgrade flutter 2.2.0
```

```
    [√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.3.0-12.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale ru-RU)
        • Flutter version 2.3.0-12.1.pre at D:\flutter
        • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
        • Framework revision f9c825981c (2 days ago), 2021-05-18 14:07:52 -0700
        • Engine revision 26e217e6c3
        • Dart version 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-edge.a527411e5100a0a4f48c4009087a1b988aa784af)

    Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter/material.dart'.
    Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.
```

[image]

What I try:

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade
flutter clean
```

restart vs code

cry :d

change channel and upgrade
delete plugins in vs code and reinstall
restart PC

Comment: Flutter 2.2 is now on the stable channel, you can (and should) switch to it: `flutter channel stable`, then of course, don’t forget to call upgrade for it to take effect.

Comment: see "what i'm try:"

Comment: My bad, I missed that. Could you add the pubspec?

Comment: im add it in bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
name: test
description: test client.
version: 4.0.703

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.13.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  rxdart: ^0.24.1
  flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface: ^2.0.0
  timezone: ^0.6.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+2
  json_annotation: ^3.1.0
  http: ^0.12.2
  firebase_core: "^0.5.2"
  firebase_messaging: "^8.0.0-dev.8"
  date_range_picker: ^1.0.6
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.4.0
  video_player: ^0.10.12+5
  url_launcher:
  chewie: ^0.9.10
  flutter_local_notifications: ^4.0.1+2
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  device_info: ^1.0.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.24
  wakelock: ^0.1.2
  sip_ua:
    path: ../modules/dart-sip-ua-master
  image_picker:


flutter_icons:
  ios: true
  android: true
  image_path_ios: "assets/launcher/icon.png"
  image_path_android: "assets/launcher/icon.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "assets/launcher/background.png"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/launcher/foreground.png"

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner:
  json_serializable: ^3.5.0
  mockito: ^4.1.1
  plugin_platform_interface: ^1.0.1

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - images/logo.png
    - images/cctvback.png
```

Comment: `image_picker` and `build_runner` don’t have the versions after it.